# How to block livechatinc.com from indexing my sensitive website pages?

Tags: php, livechat, litespeed

We use LiveChat from livechatinc.com on our company site. However we are not using it in clients panel area yet. But my boss wants to use it there.

The main problem is that some pages from client area do not require authentication, so client can click special link in message we provide by email to see some details of project without being logged in to clients area.

My boss fears that livechatinc enabled on these pages, would be crawling them and might be sharing some sensitive data.

Are these fears right?

If so, what would be the best possible way to block livechatinc?

I think that i should check ip of every request to this sensitive pages and make some kind of dns lookups that maybe would provide some info that this ip belongs to livechatinc.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you not just exclude the javascript loading Livechat from all pages containing sensitive information?

Comment: Unfortunately, it needs to be enabled there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's Agnieszka from LiveChat, Inc.

We don't have access to data of our clients. LiveChat will not be crawling them and will not share any data for sure.

Cheers!